# Select names to array from object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I have class with this fields:

```
 public class TimesheetModel
    {
        public DateTime TaskDate { get; set; }
        public List<TimesheetListModel> TimesheetList { get; set; }

        public TimesheetModel() { TimesheetList = new List<TimesheetListModel>(); }
    }
```

List<> have this structure:

```
public class TimesheetListModel
    {
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public DateTime TaskDate { get; set; }
        public string Task { get; set; }
        public decimal TimeWorked { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
    }
```

When I load my page TimesheetModel getting data from database, it works normally  and I can view data via angularjs on my page. 
But also I need to select ProjectNames to array without duplicates, because TimesheetListModel list have duplicates of ProjectName.
I write this in code like this:

```
    $scope.bindModel = function(data) {
         $scope.model = data;
         $scope.projects = function () {
            var array = [];
            array.push($scope.model[0].TimesheetList[0].ProjectName);
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < $scope.model.TimesheetList.length; j++) {
                            if ($scope.model[i].TimesheetList[j].ProjectName != array[i - 1]) {
                                array.push($scope.model[i].TimesheetList[j].ProjectName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return array;
                };
    };
```

I think I make mistake because my javascript knowledge is not good. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What is your var `model` ? It's not  `$scope.model` instead ?

Comment: @Pierre-Alexandre Moller, I rewrite code

Comment: Still same problem ?

Comment: @Pierre-Alexandre Moller, In console show error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in $scope.model.TimesheetList.lenght

Comment: On your second `for` your `$scope.model` probably need the index like this `$scope.model[i].TimesheetList.length`.

Comment: Thanks, now it works!)

Comment: I'm glad if it's help.

Answer (score 0):

> I had modified the code, which has arrayContains function which check for duplicate

```
   $scope.bindModel = function(data) {
      $scope.model = data;
      var arrayContains = function(arr, value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (arr[i] === value) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
      $scope.projects = function() {
        var array = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < $scope.model.TimesheetList.length; j++) {
            if (!arrayContains(array, $scope.model[i].TimesheetList[j].ProjectName)) {
              array.push($scope.model[i].TimesheetList[j].ProjectName);
            }
          }
        }
        return array;
      };
    };
```

> instead of writing code, you can use jQuery which has a utility function for this:

```
$.inArray(value, arr)
```

Comment: replace second for loop with this code "for (var j = 0; j < $scope.model[i].TimesheetList.length; j++)"